# Define a function to update a class integer property

Tags: python, class

I'm having issues defining a function that controls the correct "speed" (accelerate/slow down).

I currently have my code like this:

```
class Train():

    serial_nummer = 2021001

    def __init__(self, type, buildyear):
        self.type = type
        self.buildyear = buildyear
        self.serial_nummer = Train.serial_nummer
        self.speed = ()
        Train.serial_nummer += 1
        return

    def snelheid(self, speed):
        pass

    def __str__(self):
        return (f"Train type: {self.type} \nBuildyear: {self.buildyear} \nSerial number: {self.serial_nummer} \nCurrent speed: {self.speed}\n\n")

train1 = Train('Alfatrain', '2001')
train1.speed = 100
print (train1)
```

How can I create a function that controls the correct "speed"?

Now I'm just modifying the speed with train.speed = 100.

Comment: What exactly do you want the function to do? ← that one you have to figure out yourself.

Comment: You seem to understand the concepts of accessing attributes with `self` and defining methods. Maybe you can define a method that accepts an argument and increases the speed using `self` by the value of that argument?

Comment: @user202729 The function has to control the speed so either accelerate the train, do nothing or brake. I have tried a couple of things so far... I tried using a if else statement where I asked for input. Where the input would be accelerate, do nothing or brake. But that doesn't do the trick.

Comment: In your `__init__` you set the value of the attribute `speed` to an empty tuple. In my opinion it should be set to `None`: `self.speed = None`. In `snelheid` you can assign a different value to `self.speed`.

Comment: @Matthias `0` might be a better default than `None`. This will save a lot of checks when trying to increase/decrease the speed

Comment: @DeepSpace I agree and it might be even better to have an optional parameter for `speed` with a default value of `0`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't really need a function when you can use `train.speed += amount`. You will want to initialize the speed as 0, not an empty tuple, though

Without more clarity, I'm guessing instructions are looking for

```
def accelerate(self, amount):
    self.speed += amount 

def decelerate(self, amount):
    self.accelerate(-1*amount)
```

Comment: Or define one function `change_speed(self, amount)` where `amount` can be any number (positive, negative, 0).

Comment: Might be too advanced to OP's use case, but a property with a setter might actually be beneficial here (if some validations are required e.g)